# Xamarin Forms pass model value to binding converter parameter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to pass model property value like a converter parameter for other binding value.

```
<Label FontSize="{Binding MediumLabelTextSize}"
       Text="{Binding FeedHome.QuestionBody,
              Converter={StaticResource HideLongTextConverter}}"/>
<Label FontSize="{Binding SmallLabelTextSize}"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsQuestionReadMoreVisible}"
        Text="Read more">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ReadMoreCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

I want to pass  FeedHome.QuestionBody like a converter parameter for IsQuestionReadMoreVisible.
How can I do it?

Comment: Technically view shouldn't post something to view model. Command and CommandParameter are the only exception. If you have data in your view, Viewmodel should already be aware of that

Comment: IsVisible="{Binding IsQuestionReadMoreVisible, ConverterParameter={Binding Source={x:Reference LabelName}, Path=Text}}" this will also work or else you can use pass BindingContext like   "{Binding BindingContext.FeedHome.QuestionBody, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}"

Comment: why u dont use your FeedHome.QuestionBody property in your ReadMoreCommand inside your viewModel ? When tapping on label u know value of this property, or not ?

Comment: I need to set IsQuestionReadMoreVisible = true if FeedHome.QuestionBody text length more than 300 symbols, and I think to pass QuestionBody like a converter parameter for IsQuestionReadMoreVisible.

Answer (score 0):

please Try This

Text="{Binding HeaderText, Converter={StaticResource caseConverter}, ConverterParameter=u}}"
 IsVisible="{Binding IsEditMode, Converter={StaticResource boolInverter}}"